# Setting delete type to post in blueimp jquery-file-upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

My webhost doesn't support DELETE, so I'm trying to use the POST delete_type, though I can't find it documented anywhere on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki and the only mention is buried in the source code.

Does it work?

Is it supported?

If it works, how do you get the name of the file to be deleted into the HTTP POST request?  The deleteUrl only has one field, which I presume is the URL of the script you call to do the deleting, but there's nowhere to put in the file to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the type that's used is "DELETE", so you have to override that, as you've already figured out.

I'm not sure how you're using the plugin, but here's an example when using the delete button with the out-of-the-box template examples:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="POST" data-url="/YourHandler" data-data="{ fileName: 'somefile.jpg' }">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

If you're using the templated example (`tmpl.min.js`) and want to pass this back within your array of files:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" 
        data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" 
        data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}" 
        data-data='{ "fileName": "{%=file.name%}" }' {% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {% } %}>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>

files: [
  {
    name: "yourfilename",
    deleteUrl: "The handler or url to call for delete",
    deleteType: "POST"
  }
]
```

Should work then, and you can grab the filename from form posted values.